# inserting values in to temporary column from the select query

Tags: mysql

I have a select query as below and I wanted to insert text in to temp (ex: ex, ab , cbhk) of row of city and respective code and the remaining should be empty how to do in the best way. Please suggest

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    city,
    code,
    ' ' as Temp
    FROM table t1
    where value='notequal'
```

Will give output

| city | code | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bang | codea |  |
| bang | codeb |  |
| bang3 | codec |  |
| afghan | coded |  |
| afghan | codee |  |

Needed output

| city | code | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bang | codea |  |
| bang | codeb | ex |
| bang3 | codec |  |
| afghan | coded | ab |
| afghan | codee | cbhk |

Comment: not clear what you mean by "each city"; are you looking for just `select distinct city, code, case city when 'bang2' then 'a' when 'afghan' then 'b' when 'tela' then 'c' else ' ' end as Temp FROM ...`

Comment: I just have an empty table temp ' ' as Temp it creates an empty column with out any values. Now I wanted to insert values to temp for up to 30 cities with matching code column .

Comment: are you saying you have a Temp column in your table and you want to update it for specific cities?  edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of `show create table yourtablename;` and `select version();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need case condition

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    city,
    code,
    Case
    When city='bang' and code='codeb' then 'ex'
    When city='afghan' and code='coded' then 'ab'
     Else ' ' as Temp
     END
   where….
```